# Simple if statement in bash doesn't work

Tags: bash, if-statement, window

I am learning a little bit of **bash** in **Linux** and I just can't understand why this doesn't work. It is a simple `IF` statement and a `read` command to keep the window opened. What happens is that when I execute the *.sh* file the terminal's window opens for a second and closes back. I can't see any message or check whether there's any error or why it doesn't work. If I remove the `IF` block then I can see the message and the window remains opened. This is the code inside my file

```
count=99
if [ $count -eq 100 ]; then
    echo "Count is 100"
else
    echo "Count is not 100"
fi
read -p "Press enter to continue" nothing
```

I tried many other ways of using the `IF` structure but seems like none works

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. How are you executing it in the shell?

Comment: Works for me too.  The only thing I can think of is perhaps you are running this in some weird non-bash shell, and since there is no `#!/bin/bash` on the  first line of your script, it is getting interpreted by the other shell.  What happens if you put `#!/bin/bash` on the  first line of your script?

Comment: I added `#!/bin/bash`. I save the file as .sh then double-click and *Start in terminal*. I see the window for a second and then it's gone away. No message or anything. I am doing this in Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: O.K. Now I see what happens. I created the file in Windows, then I run it through Virtual Box. Must be something related to characters encoding or new lines. When I create the file in Ubuntu it works.

Comment: Hmm, I have a pretty clean Ubuntu 12.04 VM.  I created the file on the desktop, gave it executable permissions, double-clicked and clicked "Run in Terminal", and it works as expected - The output in the terminal window is `Count is not 100\nPress enter to continue`, and the window stays open until `Enter` is pressed.

Comment: Yes, but if you create the file in Windows then copy it to Linux and try to execute it that's when it will fail

Comment: @ali - See my answer - simply use the dos2unix utility to convert the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dos2unix utility to convert the text file created on Windows to the correct format for Linux.  See [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) page for more details.

Install if necessary:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dos2unix
<snip>
Setting up dos2unix (5.3.1-1) ...
$
```

Run it on your script:

```
$ dos2unix if.sh
dos2unix: converting file if.sh to Unix format ...
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is completely correct. atleast its okai in my linux mint

Comment: I have created the `.sh` file in Windows then I run it from Linux through Virtual Box. Looks like it's an encoding issue. I don't know what format is accepted by Linux.